# Machine's domain name in .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, dns

There gotta be an easy way to do this, I can't believe there's none. I have scanned through net and found, like, 20 different methods to find in which domain current user is, but none to get domain (or workgroup) of current machine.

In unmanaged c++ this is retrieved by:

```
WKSTA_INFO_100 *buf;
NetWkstaGetInfo(NULL, 100, (LPBYTE*)buf);
domain_name = pBuf->wki100_langroup;
```

can someone help me, if there's a way to get same info in managed C# natively?

EDIT1: **Folks, please read the question. I am NOT looking for user domain name.**

Comment: Hint: .NET Core doesn't have any obvious way to get this yet. I ended up P/Invoking NetWkstaGetInfo (which this question made easy to find).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To get the current domain of the system on which your progam is running you can use
[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.aspx).

```
Domain domain = Domain.GetComputerDomain();
Console.WriteLine( domain.Name );
```

Comment: If a machine isn't in domain, we'll get an exception.

Comment: @shrike - yes, you might actually want to check if domain is null before referencing the property on it.  Kind of clutters the answer, though.

Comment: Domain.GetCurrentDomain doesn't return null, it throws exception ActiveDirectoryOperationException ("Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest."). So does Domain.GetComputerDomain() (which is better to use). But the latter throws different exception. Anyway using Domain's methods isn't safe. It's safer to use NetGetJoinInformation API (mentioned by @David).

Comment: @Shrike -- as long as you know that it can throw an exception, it's not a problem. You just need to catch it and react appropriately. If you're using .NET, I think it's better to use the managed API in DirectoryServices.  I've never actually used this method, but the namespace provides some very nice abstractions.

Comment: According to Intellisense in .Net 4+ Domain.GetCurrentDomain() gets the domain object for the current user credentials in effect for the security context under which the application is running. To get the domain to which the computer belongs use Domain.GetComputerDomain(). EDIT: Just seen @Aleksandr's reply below which says the same thing

Answer (score 15):

I work on a project where users could be anywhere; non-domain users on a domain machine, users on a non-domain machine, not directly connected to the domain on a third party network, etc. so depending on AD is already a non-starter.

**System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName** is far more reliable under all of these conditions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/trobbins/archive/2006/01/04/509347.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.domainname(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            MsgBox("Domain: " & ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain.Name)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.GetType.ToString & ": " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            MsgBox("Domain: " & IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.GetType.ToString & ": " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You just saved my hide. Thank you  :-) +18 if I could.

Comment: IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName fails if the machine was removed from the domain.  It will then return the old value.

Answer (score 7):

Using **GetCurrentDomain** is the same as **Environment.UserDomainName**, which works incorrectly if your program is running on a domain computer as a non-domain user. I've used the following code:

```
try
{
    return System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain().Name;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return Environment.UserDomainName;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

System.Environment.UserDomainName

Comment: I'm running a .net application using IIS and this worked for me.

Comment: This isn't correct. The user domain name isn't necessarily the same as the machine name. In my workplace, the development machines are located in a subdomain.

Comment: This also isn't correct if the machine running your site is part of a server farm behind a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add a dependency to System.DirectoryServices, you can also call the  [NetGetJoinInformation](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetGetJoinInformation.html) API directly.

Comment: `NetGetJoinInformation` returns the legacy NetBIOS name of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetComputerDomain()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain.getcomputerdomain) wraps [DsGetDcName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dsgetdc/nf-dsgetdc-dsgetdcnamew) which will search the network for a domain controller even if the machine is not part of a domain. (see [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dsgetdc/nf-dsgetdc-dsgetdcnamew#remarks))

As alternative to [NetGetJoinInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmjoin/nf-lmjoin-netgetjoininformation) you could use [GetComputerNameEx](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getcomputernameex) with the [COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ne-sysinfoapi-computer_name_format)`.ComputerNameDnsDomain` flag to get the full DNS domain name.

(If not part of a domain, it still returns true, but the resulting string will be empty.)