# How to get Windows domain name?

Tags: c++, windows, dns

How can i get the domain name of the machine (if the machine is in fact joined to a domain)?

And, of course, if the machine is not joined to a domain the function should return

- `null`, or
- an empty string, or
- the name of the machine, or
- `"."`

**Notes**:

- the [`NetGetJoinInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 function returns the legacy NetBIOS name of the domain (e.g. `AVATOPIA`), not the name of the domain (e.g. `avatopia.local`)
- the `USERDOMAIN` environment variable returns the domain of the logged on user, which can be different from the machine; and also returns the legacy NetBIOS name of the domain (e.g. `AVATOPIA`)
- the `USERDNSDOMAIN` environment variable returns the domain name of the logged on user, which can be different from the machine

Microsoft has a knowledge base article [How to retrieve current user and domain names on Windows NT, Windows 2000, or Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111544), which relies on getting the user's security token and calling LookupAccountSid.

- the LookupAccountSid Win32 function returns the legacy NetBIOS name of the domain (e.g. `AVATOPIA`); and also returns the domain of the logged on user, which can be different from the machine

### Update One

i've also tried using ADs object to bind to the `IADs` interface of the domain:

```
IADs domain;
ADsGetObject("LDAP://rootDES", IDs, out domain);
```

problem with this approach is that:

- you cannot get the domain name (only the *distinguished name*)
- it doesn't work if the user does not have permissions to query AD
- it doesn't work if the user is not a valid user in active directory
- it only works for Active Directory domains

**Update Two**:

Just to be clear what i want is:

[image]

- which radio button is selected
- [what's in the (selected) box](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_WOWYdYK4Tg/TlPERL1jhvI/AAAAAAAABIQ/CUXUCTRU4lc/s400/se7en_movie_still.jpg)

### Bonus Reading

- [How to get fully qualified domain name on windows in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446940/how-to-get-fully-qualified-domain-name-on-windows-in-delphi) (user's domain)
- [Machine's domain name in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508911/machines-domain-name-in-net) (from .NET)

Comment: which language are you using to get it?

Comment: @tpaksu Native code, so you can assume C, C++, Delphi, C# with P/Invoke, assembly, etc. (which is a roundabout way of saying i'm not calling it from inside a Common Language Runtime, or a Java runtime, and don't have access to the .NET Framework class library, or the Java class library)

Comment: It's not clear to me why the references you cited are insufficient?

Comment: I realize you're wanting to do this from native code, but does `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain` in .NET return the desired information?

Comment: @MarkRansom Which reference are you referring to, the one that queries the domain of the user, the one from .NET, or the one that returns the NetBIOS name?

Comment: @CodyGray Not really. That attempts to bind to LDAP to find the domain name. Problem with that it throws an exception ("Logon failure: Unknown user name or bad password") when the interactive user is not a domain account. It also throws an exception if the domain controller could not be contacted. It also throws an exception if the machine is not domain joined (which could be caught, if it were not the same exception as not able to contact the domain). i presume it also fails on an non-Active Directory  domains.

Comment: Are you tried the [LsaOpenPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LsaQueryInformationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  functions ? for an example check this [How To Determine If a Windows NT/Windows 2000 Computer Is a Domain Member](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179891)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here you go:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <DSRole.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    DSROLE_PRIMARY_DOMAIN_INFO_BASIC * info;
    DWORD dw;

    dw = DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation(NULL,
                                           DsRolePrimaryDomainInfoBasic,
                                           (PBYTE *)&info);
    if (dw != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        wprintf(L"DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation: %u\n", dw);
        return dw;
    }

    if (info->DomainNameDns == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"DomainNameDns is NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"DomainNameDns: %s\n", info->DomainNameDns);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Anybody using [`DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in production use should consider calling [`DsRoleFreeMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to free the memory block when the information is no longer needed (as per discussion in the comments).

The function returns [three different domain names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), e.g.:

- **Domain Forest Name**: e.g. `stackoverflow.com`
- **Domain DNS Name**: e.g. `stackoverflow.com`
- **Domain NetBIOS Name**: e.g. `STACKOVERFLOW`

If the machine is not joined to a domain, then both *Forest* and *dns* are blank, with only NetBios name filled with the name of the workgroup, e.g.:

- **Domain Forest Name**: `null`
- **Domain DNS Name**: e.g. `null`
- **Domain NetBIOS Name**: e.g. `WORKGROUP`

The function also returns a flag indicating if the machine is joined to a domain:

- `DsRole_RoleMemberWorkstation`: workstation that is a member of a domain
- `DsRole_RoleMemberServer`: server that is a member of a domain
- `DsRole_RolePrimaryDomainController`: primary domain controller
- `DsRole_RoleBackupDomainController`: backup domain controller

or not:

- `DsRole_RoleStandaloneWorkstation`: workstation that is not a member of a domain
- `DsRole_RoleStandaloneServer`: server that is not a member of a domain

Comment: For the record, I haven't tested this on a non-domain machine.  But if it doesn't behave nicely, just use NetGetJoinInformation first to check whether you're in a domain or not.

Comment: It works on non-domain joined machines, AD domain joined machines, Windows 2000, and machines not connected to the network. i think we have a winner. i just need to figure out the difference between "dns domain name" and "forest domain name" - and which one is my domain name (http://superuser.com/questions/403447/difference-between-domain-forest-name-and-dns-name)

Comment: @wishmesh: after some consideration I decided to roll your edit back.  The call to DsRoleFreeMemory is redundant in this case because the very next thing we do is exit the program, and in production code you would typically want to keep this information indefinitely, so you wouldn't call DsRoleFreeMemory then either.  It's a small amount of data, after all.  The only reason it's in dynamically assigned memory at all is that it's of variable length.

Comment: @harry-johnston: Thanks for your comment. It seems that DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation will NOT return different information on consecutive calls. Deleted my previous comment.

Comment: I tried this on an AWS EC2 Windows 2012 R2 host as GetComputerNameExA( ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified, ...) was not giving me the public or private DNS. I got a NULL DomainNameDns .

Comment: @osullivj, that's normal behaviour if the machine isn't in a domain and you haven't explicitly set a primary DNS suffix.  You can check (and if necessary correct) these settings using the System control panel, aka "See the name of this computer".

Comment: @Harry Johnston; thanks, didn't know that. I'm looking for a completely automated way to discover the fully qualified DNS on an Amazon host, and I've settled on using the EC instance metadata eg http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname

Comment: @osullivj: in the general case, you'd want to find your IP address and do a reverse DNS query.  There are APIs for that, but not this one. :-)  In your particular case using the Amazon-specific data is probably more sensible.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`GetComputerNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301) you can get your computer name and domain name.

Example:

```
TCHAR local[100];
DWORD hstSize = sizeof(local);
GetComputerNameEx(ComputerNameDnsDomain, local, &hstSize);
```

Note: [`ComputerNameDnsDomain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724224) gives domain name and `ComputerNameNetBIOS` gives local workgroup(computer) name.

Comment: This returns the primary DNS suffix instead of the domain that the computer has joined, which can cause problems if you have a [disjoint namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/disjoint-namespace). `DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation` doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the domain name via WMI in using the [Win32_NTDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.  The link contains additional links to samples on how to interact with WMI.

Comment: The query `select * from Win32_NTDomain` seems to take about 15 seconds to return; also it doesn't work on Windows 2000.

Comment: WMI is slow and unreliable. Better use native API GetComputerNameEx() as @Sanju-Monu suggested. Also GetComputerNameEx exists in Windows 2000.