# How to find the root forest domain name using c++

Tags: c++, active-directory

I am trying to programatically find the root domain name using c++. There are lots of example of how to find the domain (I am using the example referenced there) ie:

[How to get Windows domain name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792411/how-to-get-windows-domain-name)

The example above also mentions that it returns the Forest name but I have tested it on 3 different domains and it does not while the c# example below does:

```
  [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest();
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean that it does not? Using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9798104/1202807), `info->DomainForestName` should have the forest name.

Comment: If you have non-working code, then you should post that code. Very hard to debug code that we cannot see.